# Android - ¿Como llamar una funcion de una clase simple a otra con activity?

Tags: java, android

Se que suena una pregunta muy repetitiva, sin embargo aun no encuentro lo que busco y quisiera preguntar aqui...

Mi interes es crear una clase "madre" o "manager" en donde ahi tenga todas las funciones y metodos que ocupo para mi app.

Mi interes es este:

- Crear una clase simple de Java y poner todos mis metodos
- Dentro de esta clase inicializar buttons, textviews, edittexts, (los views/widgets) de android
- Mandar llamar metodos que contengan estos elementos a otras clases que son activity

Mi pregunta es:

- ¿Como puedo realizar esto?
- ¿Es posible? ¿Como?

Answer (score 1):

No es una buena practica hacerlo, pero de forma rápida podrías crear una clase que tenga métodos estáticos donde le pases un activity, y el se encargue de inicializar variables y views que desees, algo como}:

```
public class Init {

    public static void initMainActivity(MainActivity ac) {
        ac.edit1 = ac.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        ac.edit2 = ac.findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        ac.edit3 = ac.findViewById(R.id.edit3);
    }

}
```

Pero te repito, no es una buena practica ya que quitas el sentido a todo, pero si buscas algo que facilite la vida en eso, puedes usar [ButtterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) el cual te facilita la vida a la hora de buscar los views en android

Comment: Entiendo, pero me interesa porque en todas mis activities repito mucho codigo, y en vez de estarlo copiando y pegando a cada clase por individual, me gustaria que una sola clase lo maneje y de ahi las otras clases llamen los metodos correspondientes

Comment: Entonces considera ButterKnife, dale un vistazo y veras que es mejor a la hora de obtener las referencias de views, incluso de recursos

Answer (score 0):

> Crear una clase simple de Java y poner todos mis metodos

Puedes crear una clase padre de la que extiendan tus otras clases, estos métodos obviamente serían publicos.

> Dentro de esta clase inicializar buttons, textviews, edittexts, (los
>   views/widgets) de android

Si son vistas (views/widgets) estas referencias únicamente las puedes usar en el layout que los contiene y por lo tanto en la Activity que carga este layout.

En la clase padre puedes inicializar las variables :

```
public Button myButton;
public TextView myTextView;
public EditText myEditText;
```

pero las referencias únicamente al inflar el layout contenedor.

(No recomiendo ButterKnife, es para hacer algo sencillo igual de sencillo, si la usas es porque no comprendes como obtener referencias de vistas en Android.)

> Mandar llamar metodos que contengan estos elementos a otras clases que
>   son activity

Para llamarlos estos métodos deben tener el modificador `public`.